# How to avoid the server side session creation for every page

Tags: node.js, session-cookies, express-session

New sessions are created for every page, I'm setting the token in the server-side session after the login. But it is not available on the next page a new session is created on that page How to avoid this? The database disconnects after the API call on the page. Every time the database connection is made before calling the API. I require the token throughout the login.

src/index.ts

...
const session = require("express-session")
app.use(session({
name : 'Server_ID',
secret : 'something',
resave:false,
saveUninitialized: true,
rolling: false,
cookie: {
same site: true,
// secure: "development",
httpOnly: true,
secure: false,
maxAge:1000 * 60 * 10
}
}));
...

Answer (score 0):

you must set `credentials` flag with your API call
for example if you're using axios, you do this:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

with this approach cookie is going to sent along with your request call
make sure you have correct CORS settings too.